# Horror anthology: little girl's mother returns from the dead; Indian soldier's village killed by cholera

Tags: story-identification, horror

I hope you can help me hunt down the authors/ title of this spooky horror anthology I read about 10 years ago.

One of the stories is written from the point of view of a little girl whose mother has just died. She speaks from the certain belief that her mother will come back from the dead, and sure enough one night her knock is heard at the front door. When it goes unanswered, and her attempts to break down the door fail, the mother, now a vampire/ zombie tries the back door, windows, and so on. It had a very eerie atmosphere, and you really get transported into the daughter's psyche as the story unfolds.

Another story in the anthology is about an indian soldier who returns to his remote village from a war, only to find all his family and neighbours have died from a cholera epidemic. It is the dead of the night and an evil spirit approaches him promising to bring back his family. It is however a bait, but I do not recall exactly what the trap was.

If someone has by any chance come across this anthology or know of similar stories, please let me know.